# Android : Search functionality with hint

Tags: android, search

Everybody,

I want to implement search on my app. I've been doing research here and there and some of it I can't really grasp. [Android Search Listview using Filter](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/) is one of the very helpful example.

I want to implement a search functionality that give out a hint when I start searching. Also, when I clicked on the hint, it will move to the intended page.

> For example, the hint is 'apple'. When I clicked on the hint it will directed me to the page of apple.

Is that possible?
Any site or tutorial that you can recommend for me?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you are looking for autocompletetextview. check this out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example Try this easy one Handle the event when any item is select and send an intent to particular page that you want to open.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Ramesh @PreetikaKaur Can `autocompletetextview` be implement to `searchview`?

Comment: @Mint try this https://github.com/mobisystech/autocompleteview..and nobody will make a code for you,first show some efforts..wht you tried so far?

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I'm sorry, still looking at the both github code that you give me. Just asking some clarification. Kind of really new here. It take time for me even to understand them. I'll get back to you later. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Ramesh and PreetikaKaur , I've try the `autocompletextview` . It work. Thank you :) . But I've some problem on implement the intent.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Material SearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) it worked for me.

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                //Do some magic
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //Do some magic
            }
        });
```

https://github.com/Shahroz16/material-searchview

[image]

Comment: Hi, I try the `autocompletetextview` . I'm sorry I didn't have time yet to try your suggestion. I will. I've some problem on implementing the intent for the autocompletetextview.

Comment: accept the answer if it helped..and let me know if you have any query